# how to extract particular data using pig script from web crawled data (nutch)

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig, hadoop2, nutch

This sample crawl data using nutch 2.3.1 where i need to take title and urls internal links and external links attached with website any suggestion most welcome.

I used this command to import data from hbase to pig

```
`data9 = load 'hbase://htest15_webpage' using org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('f:cnt', '-loadKey true');
```

`

```
column=f:cnt, timestamp=1487743991250, value=<!DOCTYPE htm
                  l>\x0D\x0A<!--[if IE 7]>\x0D\x0A<html class="ie ie7" lang=
                  "en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns
                  /fb#">\x0D\x0A<![endif]-->\x0D\x0A<!--[if IE 8]>\x0D\x0A<h
                  tml class="ie ie8" lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/
                  ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">\x0D\x0A<![endif]-->\x0D\x0A
                  <!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->\x0D\x0A<html lang="en-U
                  S" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"
                  >\x0D\x0A<!--<![endif]-->\x0D\x0A<head>\x0D\x0A  <meta cha
                  rset="UTF-8" /> \x0D\x0A  <meta name="viewport" content="w
                  idth=device-width" />  \x0D\x0A  \x0D\x0A<title>www.hardhe
                  ro.com</title>\x0A\x0A<!-- SEO Ultimate (http://www.seodes
                  ignsolutions.com/wordpress-seo/) -->\x0A\x09<meta name="de
                  scription" content="hardhero.com blog that provides intere
                  sting articles on general topics and ideas." />\x0A\x09<me
                  ta name="keywords" content="Internet Blog,SEO Blog,Interne
                  t Marketing Guide" />\x0A\x09<meta property="og:type" cont
                  ent="blog" />\x0A\x09<meta property="og:title" content="ww
                  w.hardhero.com" />\x0A\x09<meta property="og:url" content=
                  "http://hardhero.com/" />\x0A\x09<meta property="og:site_n
                  ame" content="www.hardhero.com" />\x0A\x09<meta name="twit
                  ter:card" content="summary" />\x0A<!-- /SEO Ultimate -->\x
                  0A\x0A<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" tit
                  le="www.hardhero.com &raquo; Feed" href="http://hardhero.c
                  om/feed/" />\x0A<link rel="alternate" type="application/rs
                  s+xml" title="www.hardhero.com &raquo; Comments Feed" href
                  ="http://hardhero.com/comments/feed/" />\x0A\x09\x09<scrip
                  t type="text/javascript">\x0A\x09\x09\x09window._wpemojiSe
                  ttings = {"baseUrl":"http:\x5C/\x5C/s.w.org\x5C/images\x5C
                  /core\x5C/emoji\x5C/72x72\x5C/","ext":".png","source":{"co
                  ncatemoji":"http:\x5C/\x5C/hardhero.com\x5C/wp-includes\x5
                  C/js\x5C/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.2.11"}};\x0A\x09\x0
                  9\x09!function(a,b,c){function d(a){var c=b.createElement(
                  "canvas"),d=c.getContext&&c.getContext("2d");return d&&d.f
                  illText?(d.textBaseline="top",d.font="600 32px Arial","fla
                  g"===a?(d.fillText(String.fromCharCode(55356,56812,55356,5
                  6807),0,0),c.toDataURL().length>3e3):(d.fillText(String.fr
                  omCharCode(55357,56835),0,0),0!==d.getImageData(16,16,1,1)
                  .data[0])):!1}function e(a){var c=b.createElement("script"
                  );c.src=a,c.type="text/javascript",b.getElementsByTagName(
                  "head")[0].appendChild(c)}var f,g;c.supports={simple:d("si
                  mple"),flag:d("flag")},c.DOMReady=!1,c.readyCallback=funct
                  ion(){c.DOMReady=!0},c.supports.simple&&c.supports.flag||(
                  g=function(){c.readyCallback()},b.addEventListener?(b.addE
                  ventListener("DOMContentLoaded",g,!1),a.addEventListener("
                  load",g,!1)):(a.attachEvent("onload",g),b.attachEvent("onr
                  eadystatechange",function(){"complete"===b.readyState&&c.r
                  eadyCallback()})),f=c.source||{},f.concatemoji?e(f.concate
                  moji):f.wpemoji&&f.twemoji&&(e(f.twemoji),e(f.wpemoji)))}(
                  window,document,window._wpemojiSettings);\x0A\x09\x09</scr
                  ipt>\x0A\x09\x09<style type="text/css">\x0Aimg.wp-smiley,\
                  x0Aimg.emoji {\x0A\x09display: inline !important;\x0A\x09b
                  order: none !important;\x0A\x09box-shadow: none !important
                  ;\x0A\x09height: 1em !important;\x0A\x09width: 1em !import
                  ant;\x0A\x09margin: 0 .07em !important;\x0A\x09vertical-al
                  ign: -0.1em !important;\x0A\x09background: none !important
                  ;\x0A\x09padding: 0 !important;\x0A}\x0A</style>\x0A<link 
                  rel='stylesheet' id='es-widget-css-css'  href='http://hard
                  hero.com/wp-content/plugins/email-subscribers/widget/es-wi
                  dget.css?ver=4.2.11' type='text/css' media='all' />\x0A<li
                  nk rel='stylesheet' id='shootingstar-style-css'  href='htt
                  p://hardhero.com/wp-content/themes/shootingstar/style.css?
                  ver=4.2.11' type='text/css' media='all' />\x0A<link rel='s
                  tylesheet' id='shootingstar-elegantfont-css'  href='http:/
                  /hardhero.com/wp-content/themes/shootingstar/css/elegantfo
```

>

Answer (score 1):

It is really hard to redproduce your usecase to provide you with the proper script as your content is not full and I cannot use is. I'll give you a general advice to use XPATH upon your text from **org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPath** package. If you have valid HTML content within you values, you'll be able to perform a set of XPATH queries which will return you the title and urls.

See this [link](https://www.teksystems.com/en/resources/teksavvy-blog/2016/how-to-process-xml-in-hadoop) for the examples of working with Pig through XPATH

Comment: Thankyou @alex let me try work on it i will get you back.